# ¿Cómo hacer un redirect al método store de un controlador desde un link a la url de login?

Tags: laravel

Tengo un link que lleva al usuario a logearse despues de completar un formulario, la idea es que una vez que se inicie sesión se envíen los datos del formulario al controlador (al método store) y se guarden en la base de datos.

Yo utilizo este enlace para redirigir a una url, pero en este caso requiero que sea al controlador.

```
<a href="{{ url('/login?redirect_to=home/booking/'.$service->id) }}" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Buy</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno teniendo en cuenta que lo quieres realizar desde el backend, lo haría de la siguiente manera:

Primero crearía un controlador --invoke y una ruta.

```
class FormularioLoginController extends Controller
{
    
    public function __invoke($data)
    {
       $_SESSION["dataForm"]= $data;
       return redirect()->route("aca-tu-ruta-login");

    }
}

Route::get("/formulario/login",[FormularioLoginController::class])->name("validar-formulario");
```

Seguidamente, suponiendo que haces una solicitud mediante Ajax.

```
function llamadaAjax()
{
    $.ajax({
    'url': "{{route('validar-formulario')}}
    'data': $("#formulario").serialize()
    success: function(){
          console.log("prueba")
      }
    })
}
```

Vinculas esa funcion al dar al boton submit de tu formulario.

```
<a onclick="llamadaAjax" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Buy</a>
```

suponiendo tu método del controlador que validas las credenciales.

```
public function iniciarSesion(....)

{

    //Tu logica
    if(/Auth::check())

   {
     return redirect()->name("aca-tu-ruta-para-store");
   }
}
```

Y finalmente desde tu metodo store

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   //Tu logica
   if(isset($_SESSION["dataForm"])
   {
      //Suponiendo que tus inputs tienen el mismo nombre de tus campos 
      de BD.
      Model::create($_SESSION["dataForm"]);
   }
}
```

Comment: El enlace lo tengo en un HTML, necesito que cuando complete el formulario lo lleve a logearse, después de logeado, envíe los datos al controlador.

Comment: Sí, primero llevar el usuario al login, y después enviar los datos del formulario al método store del controlador

Comment: Sí, correcto! así es.

Comment: Gracias, quizás me podría servir si no encuentro una solución con Laravel

Comment: Bueno desde el backend podrías, al momento de redireccionar a tu vista de login en ese controlador crear una variable de sesión PHP y almacenas ahí los datos del formulario luego si las credenciales del usuario son válidas almacenas esa variable sesión que está disponible durante la ejecución.

Comment: Suena como una opción viable

Comment: Por favor, revisar la nueva respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias, muy útil... Pero no puedo aplicarlo en este proyecto por que mi controlador es más complejo que solo guardar, igualmente me es útil para otra ocasión, ya que en este hago un tratamiento a los datos antes de guardar, con varios ciclos `for` y `foreach` condicionales `if` y validaciones.

Comment: Puedes extraer la data de la variable y operar como siempre lo haces.

Comment: Sí lo sé, tampoco te comenté que para eso no reutilizaría el código, ya que ese controlador también funciona para otro módulo del programa, entonces debería crear otro controlador para este, quizás lo termine haciendo. Muchas gracias!